# Double-slit interference pattern from double-slit diffraction pattern in the limit of zero slit-width

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, approximations

The intensity pattern of the double-slit experiment should change from the double-slit diffraction pattern $$I=4I_0{\rm sinc}^2\left(\frac{\pi b\sin\theta}{\lambda}\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi(b+d)\sin\theta}{\lambda}\right)$$ (where $b$ is the slit-width, $d$ is the length of the opaque space in between, and crucially, $I_0\propto b^2$) to that of the double-slit interference pattern
$$I=4I_0\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi d\sin\theta}{\lambda}\right)$$
when the slit-width $b\to 0$.

But what is the certainty that in the limit $b\to 0$, the maximum intensity, $I_0$, which is proportional to $b^2$, remains finite? How to do it correctly so as to end up with a finite $I_0$?

Comment: What is the difference between the *double-slit diffraction pattern* and the *double-slit interference pattern*? The pattern you get is the double-slit sin() pattern multiplied by the single slit sinc() pattern due to the slit width, and all that happens as b ⟶ 0 is that the sinc() ⟶ 1.

Comment: @JohnRennie That is what I wrote. But in the limit $b\to 0$, what happens to the intensity maximum $I_0$ which itself is proportional to $b^2$? So limit is $\lim_{b\to 0} b^2 (\sin b/b)^2$. Isn't it? (I'm not being careful about dimensions here because it's not so important for my question)

Comment: Thanks, the edit clarifies what you are asking. $I_0$ does go to zero as $b \to 0$ for the simple reason that if the slit width is zero the slits have disappeared and consequently no light can get through. But this shouldn't worry us as we can make the slits arbitrarily small and $I_0$ remains non-zero. What happens when $b = 0$ is more a question for philosophers than physicists i.e. how is a slit with zero width different from no slit at all?